# Error in ASP.NET Web API Core 5.0 with C# client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am trying to create a HTTP POST Web API in ASP.NET Core 5.0 in which I can receive any data as String like String, Int as String, or Binary, Image as Base64, in key / value pairs in a Dictionary variable `PostValues`:

Web API:

```
public class WebserviceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public String Post([FromBody] Dictionary<String, String> PostValues)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ClassResponse(true, PostValues));
    }
}
```

Client:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44395/webservice");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("Key1", "Value1");
request.AddParameter("Key2", "Value2");

IRestResponse response = client.Post<String>(request);

Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassResponse>(response.Content);
```

A generic class to pass / return data:

```
public class ClassResponse
{
    public ClassResponse(Boolean Success, Object Result)
    {
        this.Success = true;
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    public Boolean Success;

    public Object Result;
}
```

But I get error (not exception) in `response.Content`: `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-7462e05ef46bf946bc7d102a93cc479e-06107777372f8f46-00","errors":{"$":["'w' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."]}}` and `response.StatusCode` as: `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`

Comment: Thank you for the post. I immediately recalled 2010 when I was using RestClient

Comment: Since you are using net core , have you ever been thinking about using HttpClient instead?

Comment: Sure, I will use that. But I thought Restsharp is specifically built for REST api call therefore used it

Comment: Sorry , I don't know anything about Restsharp and you didn't mention using it. I think you need to add a  Restsharp tag to your question.

Comment: What's the actual request body that your client sent?